# What does this snippet from Exercise 16 from "Learn C The Hard Way" mean?

Tags: c

I am learning C from this [blog](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html). Below is some code from the blog:

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);
    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;
    return who;
}
```

I have the following doubts:

- Is Person_create the name of this function? How could a function name be a pointer? What does it signify?
- Why strdup(String Duplicate) is used just for name, not other fields like height, age, etc.

Comment: It could also be written as `struct Person* Person_create` which would be syntactically identical. Whether to put the space next to the type or next to the name is a decades-old debate.

Comment: As an aside, if `malloc` has returned `NULL` should also be checked in non-debug builds (that is, it shouldn't be done by an assertion).

Comment: The strdup is a defensive programming method, because we're using a variable length string here, not a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it would be clear the function declaration can be written the following way

```
struct Person * Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight);
```

That is the function name is `Person_create` and the function returns an object of type `struct Person *`. As you can see in its definition the function returns `who` that is defined as

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

You could write even the function declaration for example like

```
struct Person * ( Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) );
```

Take into account that for example all the following declarations are equivalent

```
int *p;
int* p;
int * p;
```

As for the second your question then it seems that data member `name` is declared like

```
char *name;
```

You need to allcoate memory that will be pointed to by `name` that to store the string pointed by parameter `name` in this memory. Function `strdup`  does two things. It allocates required memory and copies string pointed by the parameter to the allocated memory and returns pointer to that memory.

As for other data members of the structure then they are not pointers. They are objects (though a pointer is also an object but it points to other object that has to be stored somewhere). So you need not to allocate memory that to store data in these objects. The memory for these data members will be allocated when an instance of the structure will be created.

Answer (score 3):

`Person_create` is a function. It could also be written as `struct Person* Person_create` which would be syntactically identical. Whether to put the space next to the type or next to the name is a a debate as old as the C language which I refuse to get involved in.

As you might have noticed, the name-string is a pointer. When you would do just `who->name = name;` you wouldn't copy the string. You would just copy the pointer to a string. The result would be that you have two pointers which point to the same string. Why is this a problem? Imagine you make some change the name in one of the structs. The change would then also affect the other struct. This is likely not your intention.

That's why you need `strdup()`. It stands for "string duplicate". It creates a copy of a string and returns a pointer to the newly created string which can then be handled independently from the original.

Answer (score 2):

`Person_create()` is a function, which returns `struct Person *` (a pointer to a `Person` struct). It could also be written as following: `struct Person * Person_create()` or `struct Person* Person_create()`.

`strdup()` is used only for the `name` variable, as `name` is the only string (`char*`/`char` array in C) variable in the `Person` struct.

So why do you need to use `strdup()` on `char*` and you do not have to use similar functions for types like `int`?
This is because in C you pass *by value*, meaning that you will pass a value of an `int age` (which you can assign using `=`) and *a value* of `char*`. The `*char` pointer points to same place in memory, which ends with `\0` (symbol of string/`char` array termination in C). Therefore you have to use a separate function to copy all the characters between where `char* name` points to when passed to the function and the `\0` (together with the `\0`).